# How can I add third talent or fourth talent?

Tags: azerothcore

I want to add more talent for character.
I add table `character_talent` data for character but it doesn't work.

Can you share me the steps?

Comment: what do you mean "third talent"? there are 70 talents points or smthg like that

Comment: I am sorry about to describe it clearly. I mean the  talentGroup

Comment: I am sorry about to describe it not clearly. I mean the talentGroup

Answer (score 0):

Not dual specialization? 3 or 4 ?
And client supports this?

Comment: no, it requires a lot of client modification to work. I planned to have this too but it might require some hacky methods

Comment: Oh, I think that it can be realized by DB and server , I am wrong . Hope you can complete it .

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your question. If you mean more talents available for players to use, than you can do it in world configurations at the line:

```
Rate.Talent 
    Description: Talent point rate.
    Default:     1
    Rate.Talent = 1
```

Rate.Talent = 1 is the normal (default) starting at level 10 by giving you 1 talent point for each level, 71 in total.

Rate.Talent = 2 is the double rate. So if you get level 71 you will receive 142 talents points.